# Python AWS Lambda function locally using python-lambda-local

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I was testing one simple python program locally using "python-lambda-local". But getting below exceptions, though its working fine when running on AWS env.

Below is the Code.

```
import os
import json

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    what_to_print = os.environ.get("what_to_print")
    how_many_times = int(os.environ.get("how_many_times"))

    # make sure what_to_print and how_many_times values exist
    if what_to_print and how_many_times > 0:
        for i in range(0, how_many_times):
            # formatted string literals are new in Python 3.6
            print(f"what_to_print: {what_to_print}.")
        return what_to_print
    return None
```

Run this using below command - 
 $python-lambda-local -f lambda_handler lambda_handler.py event.json

Env - Windows10
Python - 3.6
Exception -

```
[root — INFO — 2018–01–13 22:14:22,138] Event: {‘what_to_print1’: ‘Hello’, ‘how_many_times1’: ‘2’}
[root — INFO — 2018–01–13 22:14:22,138] START RequestId: 7c602d94–7fa4–45ae-91db-674877eba4ef
Process Process-1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File “c:\program files\python36\lib\site-packages\lambda_local\main.py”, line 91, in execute
 with time_limit(context.timeout):
 File “c:\program files\python36\lib\contextlib.py”, line 82, in __enter__
 return next(self.gen)
 File “c:\program files\python36\lib\site-packages\lambda_local\timeout.py”, line 18, in time_limit
 signal.signal(signal.SIGALRM, signal_handler)
AttributeError: module ‘signal’ has no attribute ‘SIGALRM’

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
 File “c:\program files\python36\lib\multiprocessing\process.py”, line 249, in _bootstrap
 self.run()
 File “c:\program files\python36\lib\multiprocessing\process.py”, line 93, in run
 self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
 File “c:\program files\python36\lib\site-packages\lambda_local\main.py”, line 53, in run
 result, err_type = execute(func, e, c)
 File “c:\program files\python36\lib\site-packages\lambda_local\main.py”, line 102, in execute
 }, indent=4, separators=(‘,’, ‘: ‘))
 File “c:\program files\python36\lib\json\__init__.py”, line 238, in dumps
 **kw).encode(obj)
 File “c:\program files\python36\lib\json\encoder.py”, line 201, in encode
 chunks = list(chunks)
 File “c:\program files\python36\lib\json\encoder.py”, line 430, in _iterencode
 yield from _iterencode_dict(o, _current_indent_level)
 File “c:\program files\python36\lib\json\encoder.py”, line 404, in _iterencode_dict
 yield from chunks
 File “c:\program files\python36\lib\json\encoder.py”, line 325, in _iterencode_list
 yield from chunks
 File “c:\program files\python36\lib\json\encoder.py”, line 437, in _iterencode
 o = _default(o)
 File “c:\program files\python36\lib\json\encoder.py”, line 180, in default
 o.__class__.__name__)
TypeError: Object of type ‘FrameSummary’ is not JSON serializable

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: Not really sure. But it maybe because Windows does not have `SIGALRM`.

Comment: Your event does not look right. In JSON, you should use `"` and not `'`.

Comment: @KrishnaKumarR - I am using " within json.                                       
 `$ cat event.json
{
  "what_to_print": "Hello",
  "how_many_times": "2"
}`

Comment: Did you load the json using `json.load` when reading the file?

Comment: I have added code and execution command. I have tried this using json.load, but not able to fix.

Comment: any solution for this? same error on Windows 8

Comment: Which version of python-lambda-local are you using? https://github.com/HDE/python-lambda-local/issues/26

Answer (score 0):

It should already be fixed in v0.1.6 of python-lambda-local already.